# How to create circular animation with text in center of circle in pure CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner to CSS and having a crazy time trying to figure how to create the following:

[image]

The circle represents 100% and the filled in green would represent the 62%. Is this even possible in just CSS or would need some javascript to create?

Comment: u r asking for a solution or you want to determine how it works? did you google for 'bootstrap circular progress bar'?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry I did but wasn't ale to find anything that shows it animated. Everything I've found is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's example with [progressbar.js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/)

```js
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  color: '#7ed321',
  // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
  // prevent clipping
  strokeWidth: 5,
  trailWidth: 5,
  trailColor: '#73787d',
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  text: {
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: { color: '#7ed321', width: 5 },
  to: { color: '#7ed321', width: 5 },
  // Set default step function for all animate calls
  step: function(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

    var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
    if (value === 0) {
      circle.setText('');
    } else {
      circle.setText(value+'%');
    }

  }
});
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '3rem';

bar.animate(62*0.01);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0 //currently set to 62%
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #454b52;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600,800,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I saw this from Google but can't figure out how to do anything that not 100%.

Comment: updated the answer: bar.animate(0.62); gives you 62%

Comment: @Hopstream any luck with setting bar.animate(0.62)?

Comment: @Hopstream I updated my answer now it has even exact colors. if that helped, please do accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Created a demo with pure css-

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.page {
  margin: 40px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 40px 0 60px 0;
}
.dark-area {
  background-color: #666;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 -40px 20px -40px;
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.rect-auto {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
.pie,
.c100 .bar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.08em solid #307bbb;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.pie-fill {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.c100 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 120px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.c100 *,
.c100 *:before,
.c100 *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.c100.center {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.c100.big {
  font-size: 240px;
}
.c100.small {
  font-size: 80px;
}
.c100 > span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  color: #cccccc;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.c100:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.08em;
  left: 0.08em;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
.c100 .slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  clip: rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
}
.c100.p50 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.c100:hover {
  cursor: default;
}
.c100:hover > span {
  width: 3.33em;
  line-height: 3.33em;
  font-size: 0.3em;
  color: #307bbb;
}
.c100:hover:after {
  top: 0.04em;
  left: 0.04em;
  width: 0.92em;
  height: 0.92em;
}
.c100.dark {
  background-color: #777777;
}
.c100.dark .bar,
.c100.dark .fill {
  border-color: #c6ff00 !important;
}
.c100.dark > span {
  color: #777777;
}
.c100.dark:after {
  background-color: #666666;
}
.c100.dark:hover > span {
  color: #c6ff00;
}
.c100.green .bar,
.c100.green .fill {
  border-color: #4db53c !important;
}
.c100.green:hover > span {
  color: #4db53c;
}
.c100.green.dark .bar,
.c100.green.dark .fill {
  border-color: #5fd400 !important;
}
.c100.green.dark:hover > span {
  color: #5fd400;
}
.c100.orange .bar,
.c100.orange .fill {
  border-color: #dd9d22 !important;
}
.c100.orange:hover > span {
  color: #dd9d22;
}
.c100.orange.dark .bar,
.c100.orange.dark .fill {
  border-color: #e08833 !important;
}
.c100.orange.dark:hover > span {
  color: #e08833;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">





  <div class="dark-area clearfix">

    <!-- default -->
    <div class="clearfix">

      <div class="c100 p50 big dark">
        <span>50%</span>
        <div class="slice">
          <div class="bar"></div>
          <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <!-- /default -->



  </div>
  <!-- /.dark-area -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sahil -- is there anyway to animate that progress?